# Which versions of Dragon Ball Z count as canon?

Tags: discussion, canon

Sometimes, I stumble across a question which involves the Dragon Ball Z anime universe, and more often than not, I'm reading information that I have never heard before (and sometimes information which don't seem to make sense), despite having watched the entire show.

However, after watching some videos on Youtube, it came to my realisation: the problem comes from the fact that some (if not many) of the questions and answers are based on the English dubbed version of the anime. If you compare it with a Japanese version (with subtitles), you realise how much the conversations are different.

Notwithstanding the inconsistencies of the show as the story goes, and the fact that information is always lost in translation, the English dub not only changes some parts of the story into something completely different, but it goes as far as adding lines to characters when they aren't supposed to say anything.

To give two examples which I remember:

- During the Freeza saga, when Tenshinhan, Yamcha and Chaozu are training on Kaio/King Kai's planet and are fighting against Piccolo, the latter slams Chaozu's head into the ground. At first, the others are afraid he got killed, but a few seconds later he pops out fine. In the original version, Kaio explains that they are already dead, so it's fine (although it was retconned during the Majin Buu saga). In the English dub, I was told Kaio simply reverted time to revive Chaozu, even though it's not a power he possesses.
- During the Majin Buu saga, there's a point when Goku and Vegeta rescue their friends from inside Buu's body, and when they leave through a vent hole, they all start popping back to their original size. In the original version, they watch silently as the event unfold. In the English dub, Goku says "People popcorn!", to which Vegeta mutters "What is he on?"

As such, I can't help but wonder: which version is considered as canon to ask/answer questions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There may not be any official designation of canon, and it doesn't really matter. All versions are on-topic. Give an answer for the version that's being asked about or (even better) give an answer that covers both versions.

Unfortunately, people asking questions might not have the insight to specify what version they're watching. This just means that anyone who wants to answer may need to either ask for clarification or just know both versions that well that it doesn't matter.